# How to fire c# COM events in c++?

Tags: c#, c++, firebreath

I have an Interface in c# in which i have declared event for example:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("3839C631-AEDE-4535-9A28-15F4BFCA0C5A")]
public Interface Isample 
{
     event OnAdd(Isample sample);

}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("E81B32A2-B98C-48C0-A235-17771EE001D6")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Sample:Isample
{
    //'''''''''''''''''''''
}
```

I want to fire this event in c# and listen it into javascript through firebreath.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want to fire this event in c#" where tagged C++ comes in then?

Comment: in fire breath Roman R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COM events are very different from C# events.  They are much more generic, the event *listener* must implement an interface and tell the event source about it through IConnectionPoint.  The event source then "raises" an event simply by calling the interface method.  You thus need to:

- Write an interface that declares methods, not events.  So simply `void Add(ISample sample)` in your case.
- Don't inherit the interface in your class declaration, it is the job of the event listener to implement it.
- Declare a public event in your C# class whose name exactly matches the method in the interface
- Allow the CLR to implement IConnectionPointContainer for you by telling it about the interfaces, use the `[ComSourcesInterfaces]` attribute.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ComVisible(true)] 
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)] 
public interface IComScriptEngineEvents
{
  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="message"></param>
  [DispId((int)IComScriptEngineEventsDispatchIDs.CompileError)]
  void CompileError(string message);
}


[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("ScriptEngineComWrapper.ComScriptEngine")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IComScriptEngineEvents))]
public class ComScriptEngine : IComScriptEngine
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void CompileErrorDelegate(string message); 

    public event CompileErrorDelegate CompileError;
}
```

call then inside a method in comscriptengine
//this.CompileError("from event!");

I do not know why I have this delegate, but for some reason I had to use it. The source was written a few years ago.

VB-Script Testcode

```
Sub event_CompileError(strMessage)
  MsgBox strMessage
End Sub


Set objScriptEngine = WScript.CreateObject("ScriptEngineComWrapper.ComScriptEngine", "event_")
```

Comment: thanks Hans Passant and user743414 ! it is solved by using IConnectionPointContainer. :)